# Redirect user to HTTPS

Tags: apache, https, virtualhost

This is my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It should redirect user to https://example.com, but it doesn't work. I have this configuration for more than year, it worked, but now when I try to visit http://example.com, its display following error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

When I type http://www.example.com, apache redirects request properly. Any other redirect to different virtual host works properly too. I'm using Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Name servers have the correct information?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yeah, I checked it again, but everything is correct. As I said, everything worked well, but one day I open web through http and I got this error without any redirect.